# Form will not submit, Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

The form I am trying to use will not submit, I keep getting a 'Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation' in the console when trying.
Any help is much appreciated, I am not sure whether or not I'm accidentally using a system/reserved word which is causing the issue.

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#submit_btn").click(function() { 
        //get input field values
        var user_name       = $('input[name=name]').val(); 
        var user_email      = $('input[name=email]').val();
        var user_add1      = $('input[name=add1]').val();
        var user_add2      = $('input[name=add2]').val();
        var user_town      = $('input[name=town]').val();
        var user_country      = $('input[name=country]').val();
        var user_postcode      = $('input[name=postcode]').val();
        var user_tel      = $('input[name=tel]').val();
        var user_entries      = $('input[name=entries]').val();
        var user_freeentries      = $('input[name=freeentries]').val();
        var user_entries      = $('input[name=entries]').val();
        var user_total      = $('input[name=total]').val();
        var user_question      = $('select[name=question]').val();

        //simple validation at client's end
        //we simply change border color to red if empty field using .css()
        var proceed = true;
        if(user_name==""){ 
            $('input[name=name]').css('border-color','red'); 
            proceed = false;
        }

        //everything looks good! proceed...
        if(proceed) 
        {

            //data to be sent to server
            post_data = {'userName':user_name, 'userEmail':user_email, 'AddressLine1':user_add1, 'AddressLine2':user_add2, 'town':user_town, 'country':user_country, 'postcode':user_add1, 'tel':user_tel, 'entries':user_entries, 'freeentries':user_freeentries, 'total':total, 'question':user_question};

            //Ajax post data to server
            $.post('enter.php', post_data, function(response){  

                //load json data from server and output message     
                if(response.type == 'error')
                {
                    output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
                }else{
                    output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';

                    //reset values in all input fields
                    $('#contact_form input').val('');   
                    $('#contact_form select').val(''); 
                }

                $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();
            }, 'json');

        }
    });

    //reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
    $("#contact_form input, #contact_form select").keyup(function() { 
        $("#contact_form input, #contact_form select").css('border-color',''); 
        $("#result").slideUp();
    });

});(jQuery);
</script>
```

Here is the form for reference. it is being tested with no strange characters just plain text.

```
<fieldset id="contact_form">
                  <div id="result"></div>
                  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
                  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                  <input type="text" name="add1" id="add1" placeholder="Address Line 1" />
                  <input type="text" name="add2" id="add2" placeholder="Address Line 2" />
                  <input type="text" name="town" id="town" placeholder="Town" />
                  <input type="text" name="country" id="country" placeholder="Country" />
                  <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" placeholder="Post Code" />
                  <input type="text" name="tel" id="tel" placeholder="Telephone number" />
                  <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="entries" id="entries" placeholder="Number" />
                  <input type="text" name="freeentries" id="freeentries" placeholder="Number" />
                  <input type="text" name="total" id="total" placeholder="Cost of Entry" />

                  <select style="color:#666" name="question">
                  <option value="">Please Choose...</option>           
                      <option value="1">1</option>
                      <option value="2">2</option>
                      <option value="3">3</option>
                  </select>
                    <br><Br><br><br><br>


                  <label><span>&nbsp;</span>
                    <button class="submit_btn animate swing" data-delay="500" id="submit_btn">Enter</button>
                  </label>
                </fieldset>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
function findTotal(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('entries');
    var tot=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('total').value = "£" + tot * 50;
}

    </script>
```

Comment: What's the full error?

Comment: Note that you have a ';' at the end of your script, therefore jQuery is not passed to the variable $

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at e (js/jquery.js:4:24391)
    at Wc (js/jquery.js:4:24276)
    at Wc (/js/jquery.js:4:24299)
    at Wc (/js/jquery.js:4:24299)
    at Function.n.param (/js/jquery.js:4:24637)
    at Function.ajax (/js/jquery.js:4:20596)
    at Function.n.(anonymous function) [as post] (/js/jquery.js:4:22698)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (life/index1.html:975:15)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (/js/jquery.js:3:8066)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (/js/jquery.js:3:4767)

Comment: which ';' are you referring too, can you please be more specific, thanks

Comment: `});(jQuery);` should be `})(jQuery);`. It is currently overriding `$` to null, since you didn't pass a value. In fact, you don't even need to do this, just use `$(function() { //yourcode.. }`, see: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: I applied the change i mentioned, https://jsfiddle.net/xgyyrapy/, also i found something with: `total:total` that is causing a problem, quite strange.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function findTotal(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('entries');
    var tot=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('total').value = "£" + tot * 50;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit_btn").click(function() {
        //get input field values
        var user_name       = $('input[name=name]').val(); 
        var user_email      = $('input[name=email]').val();
        var user_add1      = $('input[name=add1]').val();
        var user_add2      = $('input[name=add2]').val();
        var user_town      = $('input[name=town]').val();
        var user_country      = $('input[name=country]').val();
        var user_postcode      = $('input[name=postcode]').val();
        var user_tel      = $('input[name=tel]').val();
        var user_freeentries      = $('input[name=freeentries]').val();
        var user_entries      = $('input[name=entries]').val();
        var user_total      = $('input#total').val();
        var user_question      = $('select[name=question]').val();
        console.log(user_total)
        //simple validation at client's end
        //we simply change border color to red if empty field using .css()
        var proceed = true;
        if(user_name==""){ 
            $('input[name=name]').css('border-color','red'); 
            proceed = false;
        }

        //everything looks good! proceed...
        if(proceed) 
        {

            //data to be sent to server
            post_data = {'userName':user_name, 'userEmail':user_email, 'AddressLine1':user_add1, 'AddressLine2':user_add2, 'town':user_town, 'country':user_country, 'postcode':user_add1, 'tel':user_tel, 'entries':user_entries, 'freeentries':user_freeentries, 'total':user_total, 'question':user_question};
            console.log(post_data)

            //Ajax post data to server
            $.post('enter.php', post_data, function(response){  

                //load json data from server and output message     
                if(response.type == 'error')
                {
                    output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
                }else{
                    output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';

                    //reset values in all input fields
                    $('#contact_form input').val('');   
                    $('#contact_form select').val(''); 
                }

                $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();
            }, 'json');

        }
    });

    //reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
    $("#contact_form input, #contact_form select").keyup(function() { 
        $("#contact_form input, #contact_form select").css('border-color',''); 
        $("#result").slideUp();
    });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Here is the form for reference. it is being tested with no strange characters just plain text.

<fieldset id="contact_form">
                  <div id="result"></div>
                  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
                  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                  <input type="text" name="add1" id="add1" placeholder="Address Line 1" />
                  <input type="text" name="add2" id="add2" placeholder="Address Line 2" />
                  <input type="text" name="town" id="town" placeholder="Town" />
                  <input type="text" name="country" id="country" placeholder="Country" />
                  <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" placeholder="Post Code" />
                  <input type="text" name="tel" id="tel" placeholder="Telephone number" />
                  <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="entries" id="entries" placeholder="Number" />
                  <input type="text" name="freeentries" id="freeentries" placeholder="Number" />
                  <input type="text" name="total" id="total" placeholder="Cost of Entry" />

                  <select style="color:#666" name="question">
                  <option value="">Please Choose...</option>           
                      <option value="1">1</option>
                      <option value="2">2</option>
                      <option value="3">3</option>
                  </select>
                    <br><Br><br><br><br>


                  <label><span>&nbsp;</span>
                    <button class="submit_btn animate swing" data-delay="500" id="submit_btn">Enter</button>
                  </label>
                </fieldset>
```

There is problem with your `post_data` serialization in `$.post` request. Check if all values in `post_data` objects are properly serialized: that means your data has to be of plain object or string or array. You can also try to set  `processData: false` in `ajax` settings (you can find list [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)).

**EDIT**: after seeing html and yur code again, it came out that instead of value of input "total" you have passed the wrong value, `total` instead of correct one `user_total`, causing error.
Correct for of `post_data. Please see corrected snippet.

Comment: Where do I start with serializing the post data... Sorry i've never gone this deep into passing form data before, be gentle...

Comment: I have edited my answer. Maybe post also your html form so we can try it in a snippet?

Comment: I have updated the question to include the form data, thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer, please see now if that works